# OnConnected throws an exception - how can I remove connection?

Tags: signalr

I have a class that inherits `PersistentConnection`. When I override `OnConnected` I check a few of the querystring parameters passed in to make sure the user is authenticated. If not I throw an exception but the client is still considered connected. How can I remove the client from the connected clients list?

```
public class NotificationConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.QueryString["example"]))
            throw new SecurityException("whatever");

        return base.OnConnected(request, connectionId);
    }

    protected override Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {            
        return base.OnDisconnected(request, connectionId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider changing your design to use the method exposed by signalr to validate users are authenticated and they have rights on the Persistent Connection

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeRequest(IRequest request)
    {
        return request.User != null && request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just send a message back to the client telling it to disconnect? e.g.

On the server.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.QueryString["example"]))
{
    Connection.Send(connectionId, "Close");
}
```

Then on the JS client do something like;

```
connection.received(function(data) {
    if ( data === "Close" ){
        connection.stop();
        // send the user to another page with window.location or warn them that their connection has been stopped.
    }
});
```

On a .net client;

```
connection.Received += data => 
{
    if ( data == "Close" )
    {
        connection.stop();
    }
};
```